# How should I parse the definition of a regular kernel?

Tags: kernel-smoothing

I was reading a paper on kernel regression, and the paper defines a non-negative kernel as **regular** if there exist $b > 0$ and $r > 0$, such that:

(1) $K(x) \ge b I\{x \in S_{0,r}\}$

(2) $\int \sup\limits_{y \in x + S_{0, r}} K(y)dx < \infty$

(Here, $x$ is a $d$-dimensional vector)

I understand what all of the symbols occurring in (1) and (2) mean, but I'm having some trouble understanding what the statements themselves mean.

At first, I thought that (1) was just a fancy way of saying that $K(x)$ must be strictly positive (since $I\{x \in S_{0,r}\}$ is either 0 or 1, and hence $b>0$ ensures that $K(x)$ will be greater than $b$, and therefore positive). But that can't be right - they would have just said "$K(x) > 0$".

As for (2), I imagine that it's saying something about how large $K(x)$ can get, but I don't understand what it has to do with $S_{0,r}$. In fact, I don't see why $S_{0,r}$ appears in either (1) or (2).

Comment: Your second condition seems to be missing something. It's an integral, but what about the integral is being assumed?

Comment: Sorry about that, I was missing an infinity sign

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So

1. is saying that $K(x)$ is at least $b$ everywhere on a ball (of radius $r$) centered at zero.  In one dimension that means it can't have a local minimum of $K(0)=0$  -- for example, it can't have peaks at $\pm 1$ and then go back down to zero in between. Or a kernel that's nominally centered at zero but has its peak at 1.  In two or more dimensions, you're also ruling out weird things like a 'valley' leading into the kernel, and spiralling in towards zero.
2. is ruling out 'spikes' in the kernel.  The supremum looks for the highest value within $r$ of each $x$. If you had one or more high, narrow spikes, you could have a situation where the integral of the supremum was infinite.

The first problem would be bad because it's hard to prove things and because the 'centre' of the kernel-weighted average could be offset from the 'real' centre.  The second problem would be bad because you aren't smoothing with a kernel like that.  I imagine it could also be a problem for proofs using the Dominated Convergence Theorem

Comment: Thanks very much - I'll give it some thought!